# How to solve cloud Firestore plugin error in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

My `Pubspec.yaml`

```
  dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  carousel_pro: ^0.0.13
  firebase_auth: ^0.6.6
  google_sign_in: ^3.2.4
  cloud_firestore: ^0.8.2+3
  firebase_storage: ^1.0.4
  fluttertoast: ^2.2.3
  shared_preferences: ^0.4.3
  image_picker: ^0.4.10
  cached_network_image: ^0.5.1
  intl: ^0.15.7
  uuid:
  firebase_database:
  flutter_search_panel: ^1.0.1
  flutter_typeahead: ^1.4.0

flutter:

  uses-material-design: true
  module:
    androidX: true
```

But even though I am receiving the error:

```
C:\Users\RIDDHI\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.8.2+3\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\cloudfirestore\CloudFirestorePlugin.java:8: error: package android.support.annotation does not exist
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
                                 ^
C:\Users\RIDDHI\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.8.2+3\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\cloudfirestore\CloudFirestorePlugin.java:9: error: package android.support.annotation does not exist
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
                                 ^
C:\Users\RIDDHI\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.8.2+3\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\cloudfirestore\CloudFirestorePlugin.java:253: error: cannot find symbol
          public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                 ^
  symbol: class NonNull
C:\Users\RIDDHI\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.8.2+3\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\cloudfirestore\CloudFirestorePlugin.java:274: error: cannot find symbol
                    public Void apply(@NonNull Transaction transaction)
                                       ^
  symbol: class NonNull
C:\Users\RIDDHI\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.8.2+3\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\cloudfirestore\CloudFirestorePlugin.java:272: error: cannot find symbol
                    @Nullable
                     ^
  symbol: class Nullable
C:\Users\RIDDHI\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.8.2+3\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\cloudfirestore\CloudFirestorePlugin.java:503: error: cannot find symbol
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                           ^
  symbol: class NonNull
C:\Users\RIDDHI\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.8.2+3\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\cloudfirestore\CloudFirestorePlugin.java:558: error: cannot find symbol
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                           ^
  symbol: class NonNull
```

Im trying to use code of https://github.com/Santos-Enoque/admin_side_flutter_ecommerce_app/tree/product_details,
Can someone please help me in understanding why this error is occurring and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from one or more packages versions being so outdated they are not yet migrated to androidx. Start by updating `cloud_firestore` to the latest version (**0.14.0+2** right now). Do the same if another package is throwing errors afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

First update the plugins versions (if you already didn't) and I also would suggest adding

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

to your `gradle.properties` file (it's in the android folder of your project)

Comment: Yes that is there